# How to aggregate tests count from different languages modules with Sonarqube?

Tags: javascript, java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using Sonarqube on a Maven multi-module projects which contains Java and Javascript modules.

All my tests results are (seems to be) read by Sonarqube as the code coverage looks good. When I check files by files, it also looks covered properly.

However, the amount of tests ran on the project homepage is incorrect: I only have the amount of Java tests (617). The Javascript tests count is missing (1646).

Here are my Sonar properties in the root pom.xml:

```
<sonar.projectVersion>${project.version}</sonar.projectVersion>
<sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>

<java-module-1sonar.projectKey>module1</java-module-1sonar.projectKey>
<java-module-1sonar.projectBaseDir>../module1</java-module-1sonar.projectBaseDir>

<java-module-2sonar.projectKey>module2</java-module-2sonar.projectKey>
<java-module-2sonar.projectBaseDir>../module2</java-module-2sonar.projectBaseDir>

<java-module-3sonar.projectKey>module3</java-module-3sonar.projectKey>
<java-module-3sonar.projectBaseDir>../module3</java-module-3sonar.projectBaseDir>

<javascript-modulesonar.projectKey>module4</javascript-modulesonar.projectKey>
<javascript-modulesonar.projectBaseDir>../module4</javascript-modulesonar.projectBaseDir>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to configure something on the Sonarqube server part?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what I was missing:

- First, I was not generating the unit test report within my karma.conf.js
- Then, I found a very useful Sonar report for karma: karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter
- Finally, I updated my pom.xml to use generic test result (sonar.testExecutionReportPaths property)

Now it works perfectly. I hope my struggle could help other people :)